# Matlab: Update an excel sheet

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab to read a workbook with a bunch of sheets in it.

I do some calculation and have to update one particular column in one sheet. I tried using xlswrite after xlsread, it does not work.

So, my code looks something like:

```
[~,~,Data] = xlsread('MyFile.xlsx', 'MySheet');
Data(2:end-1,5) = Data(2:end-1,5) + 1.5; %Random operation for illustration only
ret = xlswrite('MyFile.xlsx',Data,'MySheet');
```

But ret is 0. So, I am not able to achieve replacement process. Can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: Please use the second output argument as well an check what message you get: `[status,message] = xlswrite(filename,A,sheet)` Hopefully that is sufficient to find the cause, please let us know if that's the case.

Comment: You were right, looking at the message solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Please add your comment as an answer so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own comment:

Please use the second output argument as well an check what message you get:

```
[status,message] = xlswrite(filename,A,sheet)
```

Hopefully that is sufficient to find the cause, please let us know if that's the case.

---

Apparently it was indeed sufficient for the asker.